# ASP MVC 3 support for multiple row editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I was wondering if ASP MVC 3 has in-built support for editing multiple rows? I've found a fair bit of ASP MVC 2 examples floating around, but nothing for v3. I'm using Entify Framework 4 as the back-end. Suppose you have a

```
public class Order 
{
    public List<OderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public bool Checked {get; set;} 
    public int Amount {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
}
```

Creating or editing an order should be presented as a header with the order info and then a table with the lines, where each line can be changed, or deleted, and new rows can be filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC has no built-in support for such things. It has support for Models, Views, Controllers and a couple of HTML helpers. From there you can implement everything you want. You may checkout the [MvcContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) or [Telerik Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) for creating nice looking grid components allowing you to CRUD data.

There's also the [WebGrid helper](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/154/Looking-At-The-WebMatrix-WebGrid) which is part of WebMatrix but this is something that I personally don't like and wouldn't recommend but some people find it useful so worth checking out as well.

Comment: The first link seems to be for MVC2??, the second costs $999.

Comment: @Carlo V. Dango, the first link works perfectly fine with ASP.NET MVC3, you even get a NuGet package for it, I am using it in production with great success within my ASP.NET MVC 3 applications. As far as the second link is concerned Telerik provide also [GPLv2 components](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) on CodePlex including a grid.